# MySQL query for data by step size in a given range

Tags: mysql

So basically I have a users table which has a column named "completed_surveys" which holds total number of completed surveys.

I need to create a query which would take step size number and would group them by that range.

**Example result which would suit my needs:**

```
+---------+-------------------+
|  range  | completed_surveys |
+---------+-------------------+
| 0-14    |              4566 |
| 14-28   |              3412 |
| 28-42   |              5456 |
| 42-56   |                33 |
| 56-70   |                31 |
| 70-84   |               441 |
| 84-98   |               576 |
| 98-112  |                23 |
| 112-126 |                12 |
| 126-140 |                 1 |
+---------+-------------------+
```

**What I have so far:**

```
select concat(what should i add here??) as `range`,
       count(users.completed_surveys) as `completed_surveys` from users WHERE users.completed_surveys > 0 group by 1 order by users.completed_surveys;
```

I think this query is correct however in the concat function I don't really know how to increase the previous number by 14. Any ideas?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query?__=1753130441

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to first create a helper table with values 0..9 .

```
CREATE TABLE tmp ( i int );
INSERT INTO tmp VALUES (0) , (1) ... (9);
```

Then join the two tables:

```
SELECT concat(i,' - ',(i+1)*7) as `range`,
  count(users.completed_surveys) as `completed_surveys` from users
INNER JOIN tmp ON (users.completed_surveys>tmp.i AND users.completed_surveys<=(i+1)*7)
WHERE users.completed_surveys > 0 
GROUP BY tmp.i
ORDER BY tmp.i
```